# How to assign one input when matrix keypad key is held down?

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, hardware, rpi.gpio

I have a simple matrix 3x4 keypad that executes a function based on the code entered. However I'm running into the issue when someone holds down a key. I would like it to where only one value is recorded. For example if I hold down 1, I only want 1 untill I release the button. I have a delay for accidental sticky keys but for those who are slow typers, that method won't cut it. Thanks for any feedback!

```
import time
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_matrixkeypad

cols = [digitalio.DigitalInOut(x) for x in (board.D26, board.D20, board.D21)]
rows = [digitalio.DigitalInOut(x) for x in (board.D5, board.D6, board.D13, board.D19)]
 
keys = ((3, 2, 1), (6, 5, 4), (9, 8, 7), ("#", 0, "*"))
 
keypad = adafruit_matrixkeypad.Matrix_Keypad(rows, cols, keys)

secretCode = "4789"
input = ""

def checkPassCode ():
    global input
    if(input == secretCode):
        print("Access Granted!")
    else: print("Wrong Code")

while True:
    keys = keypad.pressed_keys
    if keys:
        print("Pressed: ", keys)
        if(keys[0] == 1):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "1"
        if(keys[0] == 2):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "2"
        if(keys[0] == 3):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "3"
        if(keys[0] == 4):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "4"
        if(keys[0] == 5):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "5"
        if(keys[0] == 6):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "6"
        if(keys[0] == 7):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "7"
        if(keys[0] == 8):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "8"
        if(keys[0] == 9):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "9"
        if(keys[0] == 0):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input += "0"
        if(keys[0] == '*'):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            input = ""
        if(keys[0] == '#'):
            checkPassCode()
        print(input)
        
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: `I only want 1 untill I release the button` ... test for button release then .... or record a keypress only if there is a transition

Answer (score 0):

You will have to track presses and releases separately. Unfortunately, the adafruit_matrixkeypad library will not do this for you. So you will have to resort to manual polling.

Each time through your `while True` loop, set a boolean value for each key currently pressed. This represents the "pressed state." For each key not currently being pressed, check your saved "pressed state." If it was "true" then you know the user has just released the button! Add it to your "input" variable, and clear the boolean state for that key.

It's important not to `time.sleep(0.1)` between these lines, or you will miss a lot of press/release events.

---

It might seem counterintuitive to perform your action on "key release" events, but actually this is how most button algorithms work.